# Django manage.py shell save() doesn't save to postgresql database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new to Django. Testing out a simple application (`test_cedar_app`) with a PostgreSQL database called `test_cedar`. I have the following model for the application:

```
class answer_key(models.Model):
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text
```

I made a migration and applied it, and verified in my psql command-line client with `\dt` that the schema was created properly.

I opened the Django command-line client using `python manage.py shell` and entered the following:

```
ak_1 = answer_key(answer_text='Yes')
ak_2 = answer_key(answer_text='No')
ak_1.save()
ak_2.save()
```

These appeared to save, as the following revealed that the full query set for answer_key contains ak_1 and ak_2:

```
from test_cedar_app.models import answer_key
answer_key.objects.all()
```

returned

```
<QuerySet [<answer_key: Yes>, <answer_key: No>]>
```

However, if I then enter the psql command-line (`psql test_cedar`), and enter the following:

```
SELECT * FROM test_cedar_app_answer_key
```

Nothing appears. Why do my changes not propagate to the database as it appears within the psql command-line tool?

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing at the same instance of the database in the Django code and when using psql?

Comment: As a sidenote, when you're creating your models, you should stick to python's naming conventions. It's a class, it should start with a capital letter and be CamlCase.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yup, I'm pretty sure I am, as this is in my settings.py file: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_cedar',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '************',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

Comment: So if you look at the Postgres log do you see the rows being inserted?

Comment: could it be that you just forgot the `;` at the end of your SQL request? sounds stupid but I do the mistake myself sometimes

Comment: @KevinEaverquepedo oh my goodness, that is exactly what I did (sigh). Thank you.

Comment: haha, happens to me all the time. I realize after frantically trying 5 requests that none of them have `;` :)

Answer (score 0):

When you login to psql, you are not logged in the project's database. Normally when you configure Django, in your settings somewhere, you must have a DATABASE_NAME.
I actually get these settings from environment variables by using https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/, but normally somewhere you do provide a DB name: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup

So if you know your db name, after going into psql, just type `\c db_name`

Or you can simply provide the db name directly in your psql command.

You can see the list of tables in your psql DB by typing `\dt`, that helps to know you're in the right DB

Comment: Except @Charly Phillips was logging into project database ```psql test_cedar``` and the select for the table(```SELECT * FROM test_cedar_app_answer_key```) did not error it just did return anything.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I am in the correct database, as settings.py contains the following: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_cedar',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '***************',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}                                                                                                                                               Entering `psql test_cedar`, then`\dt`, shows the answer_key table. It just does not save instances created in the shell.

Comment: Well, it must be saving them, there must be something wrong when retrieving them, because when you are doing `answer_key.objects.all()` it's actually querying the DB and finding the rows.